# Implementing captive portal

Tags: captivenetwork

I have researched around a bit where all of the captive portals are little bit complicated in terms of configuration.

1. I dont need AAA , I would just show a webpage where user will be click yes accept terms and then it will redirected.
2. I am using ignite cloud controller to manage the access points.
3. Implementing a service where I would like fetch SSID from a repository to match incoming SSID and then redirect based on the SSID.

I am trying to build something externally. My networking skills are pretty new.

I am confused how to get IPAddress and Necessary details from the access point there is an option in ignite cloud controller where I can specify the external settings for captive portal. (Like If my captive portal is running on remote IP, I know I can capture request incoming from access point. How? Can I build a normal web service to do that?)

I think it is straightforward implementation but little guidance is required.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the above by creating a simple web service which filters the request sent from the ACCESS POINT.

1. There was an option in ignite cloud where I could redirect to my web-service
2. Once AP redirect I have to set variables in the request forwarding it back to AP with res=success.

Then it will allow me to browse web as expected.

Thanks